# Macro that disable / enable sound device in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, macros

What should I use to program that kind of Macro ?

Answer (score 2):

[Autohotkey!](http://www.autohotkey.com)

Look up the "SoundSet" function to achieve what you want here.

Comment: Can I do this without a program like AutoHotKey, I can do macros with my Razer Tarantula I'd like to use that if possible

Comment: You asked what program you could do it with, I gave you an answer. If you don't want a certain type of answer, *put that in the question*, Razer Tarantula we're not telepaths. I've never used such a keyboard, so I don't know, but AHK would still be fit for the task.

Comment: I'm trying at the moment and I can't seem to make it work with Windows 7 sound devices

Comment: I listed all the sound devices, a few are there but not the one I want to change settings, I'm using USB headphones

Answer (score 1):

You may use [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) from Microsoft

> The DevCon utility is a command-line
>   utility that acts as an alternative to
>   Device Manager. Using DevCon, you can
>   enable, disable, restart, update,
>   remove, and query individual devices
>   or groups of devices. DevCon also
>   provides information that is relevant
>   to the driver developer and is not
>   available in Device Manager.

the page contain a detailed set of information about how to use it,

for your case, just put

`devcon find *`

To lists device instances of all devices that are present on the local computer.then,

`devcon disable <your-sound-card-HardwareID>`

to disable devices that match the specific hardware or instance ID,you can use wildcard (*)

Answer (score 1):

Find what registry values your particular Macro queries, you can do this with [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

For me, the calculator key on my keyboard queries the value of

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\18\ShellExecute
```

which is set to "calc.exe".

Change that value to use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to mute the device or the previously mentioned [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) to disable the device.

example:

to mute

```
C:\path\to\nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1
```

to unmute

```
C:\path\to\nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 0
```

or to disable

```
devcon disable [hardware_id]
```

and re-enable

```
devcon enable [hardware_id]
```